# SQL Fiddle - date format not recognized

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlfiddle

So as someone advised me yesterday I'm using SQL Fiddle since it's an easy way to test database queries and SQL programming in general but I'm getting this error:

```
Schema Creation Failed: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

This happens in the insert line. This usually works in Oracle and I selected in the combobox on top of the page Oracle 11g. So what's the problem?

```
create table Reparacoes(
numero_r int,
matricula char(8),
dataEntrada date,
constraint pk_carro primary key(numero_R),
constraint check_matricula check (regexp_like(matricula,'[[:number:]]{2}-[[:alpha:]]{2}-[[:number:]]{2}')));

insert into Reparacoes values (1,'S2-SS-12',to_date('yyyy-mm-dd','2013-11-10'));
```

Comment: You're using the function wrong: [TO_DATE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132)

Comment: What an idiot, it's the other way around. I'm so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Plus one vote for the cool user name.

Comment: consider deleting this question or adding the answer yourself.

Comment: I've answered myself then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my own stupidity I was using the `to_date` wrongly. It's supposed to be like this:

`to_date('2013-11-10','yyyy-mm-dd'));`

and not like this:

`to_date('yyyy-mm-dd','2013-11-10'));`

Comment: If you're already using ISO date formats then you might as well use date literals.  For example: `values(..., date '2013-11-10', ...`.  You almost never need to use `TO_DATE`.

Comment: Never seen that. Going to test right now !

Comment: `insert into Reparacoes values (1,'99-ZZ-99', date '2013/11/10');` like this ?

Comment: You need to use `-` instead of `/`.  E.g., `date '2013-11-10'`.

Comment: Works like a charm. That saves me so much time. Thank you !